# HTML page sending form data to PHP page

Tags: php, html

My html page 'nameinfo' has this on it:

```
<body>
    <form action="name.php" method="post">
    First Name: <br>
    <input type="text" name="firstname"> <br>
    Last Name: <br>
    <input type="text" name="lastname"> <br> <br>
    <input type="submit" value="submit data">
    </form>
</body>
```

Now this data the user enters is supposed to send to a page called 'name.php'. When the page opens up all it shows is my php code. Why is this. Where should i put the name.php page?

Comment: show your php code too .. seems you haven't put php tag `<?php`

Comment: Both pages  should be in `xampp/htdocs` folder.

Comment: As other people have implied, we need more information.
You need to be sure you are using a server configured for PHP, and if that is your local machine, that you are accessing it through the server, not as a local file.
As kamal pal mentioned you need the <?php tag for the parser to know what portions of the code are PHP.
As the file is named .php by default, any server would know it's PHP, but you could check which extensions it recognizes as PHP.
etc etc

Answer (score 0):

create a page called name.php

```
 <?php
        $firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
        $lastname  = $_POST['lastname'];
        echo  $firstname;
    ?>
```

It will show the Firstname data...

Answer (score 0):

put this in your name.php and it will display all the data containing in your POST method at name.php.

```
<?php
     echo "<pre>";
     print_r($_POST);
?>
```